# VBA match Greek words as whole words using regular expression

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to match greek characters in a regex pattern. It seems that VBA is quite limited on supporting Unicode, but I can do with ASCII if possible. Here is a sample code:

```
Sub TestGreekRegEx()
Dim str 
str = "αυτό είναι ένα ελληνικό κείμενο"
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
regEx.Pattern = "\b[\xe1-\xfe]+\b"
Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)
For Each Match In Matches
    MsgBox Match
Next
End Sub
```

This return no matches at all. Also, if I loop in the str's character the ASCII codes that I get is within the range of \xE1 to \xFE.

Thank you

Comment: Can you do something like this `\p{IsGreek}` as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-7 (I think it's vb.net, but I don't know the differences between the two and can't find equivalent docs for VBA).

Comment: Try `\u` instead of `\x` for unicode.

Comment: `\p{IsGreek}` is .net and does not work in vba

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
\b[\u00E1-\u03CE]+\b
```

BTW, make sure to handle range of UNICODE characters.

Comment: This doesn't work "as-is". The str string is ASCII. I tried `regEx.Execute(StrConv(str, vbUnicode))` but does not work as well...

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the Greek char Unicode character range aside, you have another problem: `\b` in ECMAScript 5 standard only ASCII matches boundaries.

Thus, whatever Greek word pattern works for you, `[\u00E1-\u03CE]+` or `[\xE1-\xFE]+`, if you add `\b`s on both ends, you won't get a match.

So, what you need to do is *build custom boundaries* using a group (on the left) and a lookahead (on the right). To extract the words, you will need to access the `.Submatches` property of each match.

I do not have Greek language settings set for non-Unicode files, so let me imaging your word pattern is `[\xE1-\xFE]+`. Then, your *extracting* regex will look like

```
(?:^|[^_0-9\xE1-\xFE])([\xE1-\xFE]+)(?![_0-9\xE1-\xFE])
```

With `[\u00E1-\u03CE]+` pattern, it will look like

```
(?:^|[^_0-9\u00E1-\u03CE])([\u00E1-\u03CE]+)(?![_0-9\u00E1-\u03CE])
```

Note I am imitating `\b` word boundaries with `(?:^|[^_0-9\xE1-\xFE])` on the left (it matches start of string or any char BUT `_`, digit and the letter from your character range) and `(?![_0-9\xE1-\xFE])` on the right (no digit, `_` and your chars allowed right after the word matching pattern). Note the word matching pattern is wrapped with parentheses to *capture* it into a group. The "problem" is that the non-capturing group (`(?:^|[^_0-9\xE1-\xFE])`) match also lands in the result. That is why we need to access `.Submatches`:

```
Sub TestGreekRegEx()
Dim str 
str = "YOUR_NON_ASCII_STRING_HERE"
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
regEx.Pattern = "(?:^|[^_0-9\xE1-\xFE])([\xE1-\xFE]+)(?![_0-9\xE1-\xFE])"
Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)
For Each Match In Matches
    MsgBox Match.Submatches(0)  ' <--- See here
Next
End Sub
```