# Problems while adding symbols in VBA string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a requirement where I need to check a document for text that may contain symbols like `°` and `β`.

I used the below code to add the text to a dictionary.

```
dict.Add Chr(176) + "C", "degrees Celsius"
dict.Add Chr(223) + "-hCG", "beta-human chorionic gonadotropin"
```

Further, the below code takes the dictionary key and puts it in a regex, so that I can scan my document using it.

```
Document_Search = "\b" & dict.keys()(ia) & "\b"
Dim regEx, Match, Matches
Set regEx = New regExp

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = Document_Search
End With
```

The code is working fine on my system, which has only one language installed - `English (United States)`.

However, when somebody tries to run the code on a Windows 10 system that has `Chinese (Simplified)` also installed, we are getting an error.

**Run time error 5018, Application-defined or object-defined error**

I am not sure if the extra language is the actual cause; this is the only difference that I can think of right now.

I added Chinese (Simplified) to my system, but did not get the error.

How can I work around this error, and use the symbols in my code?

**EDIT**: I have debugged the code on the system with the issue.

The values added to the dictionary are `?C` and `?-hCG`; whereas on my system they are `°C` and `β-hCG`.

My regex comes out to be `Document_Search : "\b?C\b"`.

Why is `Chr(176)` not working as expected?

Comment: No idea, really, but... Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: @CindyMeister Error 5018 seems to be regarding regular expressions, as mentioned in questions like these : https://superuser.com/questions/62456/why-does-my-regular-expressions-invoke-error-5018-in-my-vba-script-in-excel

Comment: No, I asked which line of code is triggering the error? If it's none of the lines you show then provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CindyMeister I am getting error in the regex, but the cause is the value added to the dictionary. I have added details.

Comment: I can't test it, but I'm wondering whether it has to do with the "code page" used by the other machine, meaning ANSI 176 would be something else. Try `ChrW(176)` and see if that makes a difference? (That would treat the symobl as Unicode.)

Comment: after using `ChrW(176)`, I am able to run the code without any issues. however, I can't match the symbols in the document. Similar behavior has been reported in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602843/vba-match-greek-in-regular-expression

Comment: Why are you using regex in Word?

Comment: After some thought, my best guess as to the "why" is that the information in the Word document is not coming in as `ChrW` only `Chr` so the comparison isn't working. To test this you use a very small document, use code to convert every character in the string you pass to RegEx to `ChrW` and see if that works.

Comment: The problem with the regex is simple to explain: `\b` is a zero-width assertion, and zero-width assertions (and start of the pattern) cannot be quantified in a ECMAScript regex. `?` means the preceding token can be matched 1 or 0 times, and it is not allowed here. And as for handling Chinese Trad. in Win10, I could not make it work, thus, I just created a VSTO Add-in in Visual Studio to do the handling for me. If anyone knows a VBA solution, I'd be glad to hear.